# using scipy.optimize.fmin_bfgs for logistic regression classifier leads divide by zero error

Tags: python, numpy, data-mining, logistic-regression

I'm trying to implement my binary logistic regression classifier and I decided to use scipy.optimize.fmin_bfgs to minimize the objective function (loglikelihood) as stated in the following formula:

[image: loglikelihood]

The gradient of this objective function is calculated as:

[image]

where:

[image]

Now I have my LogisticRegression class which has the sigmoid function to calculate the sigmoid, the loglikelihood function to calculate the loglikelihood, and gradient to calculate the gradient. Finally, I have my learn_classifier method which calls the optimize.fmin_bfgs function to find the best weight vector. My training data set consists of 2013 tuples and each tuple has 113 attributes where the first attribute is the outcome (taking either one or zero).   Here is my code:

```
from features_reader import FeaturesReader
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize
from scipy.optimize import check_grad


class LogisticRegression:
    def __init__(self, features_reader = FeaturesReader()):
        features_reader.read_features()
        fHeight = len(features_reader.feature_data)
        fWidth = len(features_reader.feature_data[0])
        tHeight = len(features_reader.test_data)
        tWidth = len(features_reader.test_data[0])

        self.training_data = np.zeros((fHeight, fWidth))
        self.testing_data = np.zeros((tHeight, tWidth))

        print 'training data size: ', self.training_data.shape
        print 'testing data size: ', self.testing_data.shape
        for index, item in enumerate(features_reader.feature_data):
            self.training_data[index, 0] = item['outcome']
            self.training_data[index, 1:] = np.array([value for key, value in item.items() if key!='outcome'])

    def sigmoid(self, v_x, v_weight):
        return 1.0/(1.0 + np.exp(-np.dot(v_x, v_weight[1:])+v_weight[0]))

    def loglikelihood(self, v_weight, v_x, v_y):
        return -1*np.sum(v_y*np.log(self.sigmoid(v_x, v_weight)) + (1-v_y)*(np.log(1-self.sigmoid(v_x, v_weight))))

    def gradient(self, v_weight, v_x, v_y):
        gradient = np.zeros(v_weight.shape[0])
        for row, y in zip(v_x,v_y):
            new_row = np.ones(1+row.shape[0])
            new_row[1:] = row
            y_prime = self.sigmoid(new_row[1:], v_weight)
            gradient+=(y_prime-y)*new_row
        return gradient

    def learn_classifier(self):
        result = optimize.fmin_bfgs(f=self.loglikelihood,
                               x0=np.zeros(self.training_data.shape[1]),
                               fprime=self.gradient,
                               args=(self.training_data[:,1:], self.training_data[:,0]))
        return result


def main():
    features_reader = FeaturesReader(filename = 'features.csv', features_file = 'train_filter1.arff')
    logistic_regression = LogisticRegression(features_reader)

    result = logistic_regression.learn_classifier()
    print result


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The FeaturesReader class is the parser that reads the csv file which I did not paste here. But I'm pretty sure the init function correctly parses the csv into a 2-D numpy array that represents training data . This 2-D array has shape (2013, 113) where the first column is the training output .  When I ran the learn_classifier function it gives these warning and terminates:

```
training data size:  (2013, 113)
testing data size:  (4700, 113)

logistic_regression.py:26: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
  return 1.0/(1.0 + np.exp(-np.dot(v_x, v_weight[1:])+v_weight[0]))

logistic_regression.py:30: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
  return -1*np.sum(v_y*np.log(self.sigmoid(v_x, v_weight)) + (1-v_y)*(np.log(1-self.sigmoid(v_x, v_weight))))

logistic_regression.py:30: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
  return -1*np.sum(v_y*np.log(self.sigmoid(v_x, v_weight)) + (1-v_y)*(np.log(1-self.sigmoid(v_x, v_weight))))

Warning: Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.
     Current function value: nan
     Iterations: 1
     Function evaluations: 32
     Gradient evaluations: 32
```

So I got these three errors: 1. divide by zero error, 2. overflow encountered in exp 3. invalid value encountered in multiply. And the algorithm terminates after first iteration which is abnormal.   I have no clue why these are happening? Do you guys think I did something wrong in calculating the loglikelihood and gradient ?  Where else do you think these errors originate? To be more specific, in my loglikelihood function,  my w_weight paramenter is assumed to be 1D (shape = 113), my v_x is 2d and has shape (2013,112) (because I do not count the outcome column), and my v_y is 1d and has shape (2013).

Answer (score 1):

I've been dealing with problem myself. The the call to `np.exp` can very quickly create numbers large enough that they overflow a float64. Even using numpy's `longdouble` datatype (which [*may*](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html#extended-precision) provide more resolution, depending on your CPU) I run into numerical issues.

I found that at least in some case, using feature scaling and normalization solve numerical problems. If you have `n` features, for each subtract the mean from that feature, then divide by the standard deviation of the feature. The numpy code is:

```
for row in X.shape[0]:
    X[:, row] -= X[:, row].mean()
    X[:, row] /= X[:, row].std()
```

There's probably a more vectorized way to do it without the explicit loop. : )

You can also look at my [toy implementation of it here](https://github.com/liavkoren/ng-redux/blob/master/ex2/Logistic%20regression.ipynb).

Alternatively, you could look at this technique, [which describes taking the log of the exponential in order to prevent overflow](https://web.archive.org/web/20160316224308/http://lingpipe-blog.com/2009/06/25/log-sum-of-exponentials/).